# Dismissing the keyboard after calling viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uicollectionview

I am implementing `UISearchController` in `UICollectionView`, i defined search controller in `viewDidLoad` to set the search result update:

```
searchControllerCollection.searchResultsUpdater = self
```

This is `searchResultsUpdater` method :

```
  func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController)
    {
        ....
        self.CollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

And here is `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    var header : UICollectionReusableView!

    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {

        header = self.CollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        header.addSubview(searchControllerCollection.searchBar)

    }

    return header

}
```

The issue happening when i tap on the search controller, then it calls `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` then it reloads CollectionView then it calls at the end `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` and the keyboard of search controller is dismissed and search controller is still active.(i can say that the keyboard is being presented for 1 second and dismissed and sometimes after writing one letter because its calling CollectionView to reload the data).How can i keep my keyboard presented ? is there is anyway to avoid calling `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` again ?